# c# chart1.Series.Clear()

Tags: c#, charts

```
for (int i = 0; i < intarr.Length; i++)
{
    Series series = this.chart1.Series.Add(strarr[i]);

    series.Points.Add(intarr[i]);
    series.XValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
}
```

This is my code and I have

```
chart1.Series.Clear();
```

at the top of the function I'm calling.
The first time round, it's fine. However the second time I get this error

```
A chart element with the name 'NSW' already exists in the 'SeriesCollection'.
```

at this line

```
Series series = this.chart1.Series.Add(strarr[i]);
```

Thanks

Comment: How do i do that.. That's why I'm here.

Comment: i guess your strarr which contains series name should added at the begining of function in a separate for loop and each series value in next for loop! Is the length of strarr is the same as intarr?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `strarr` has two elements with the name "NSW". You'll either have to catch the exception (I assume it throws an exception) or check that there isn't already an element with that type.

Comment: that's why im doing
"chart1.Series.Clear(); 
To remove everything

Comment: I think he's saying you have two `NSW` in your string array, so it's trying to create another series with the same name ..

Comment: @Andy By "first round" do you mean the first time the function is called or first time through the for loop?

Comment: First time the function is called, I want it so the second time it re creates it.

Answer (score 0):

Well this error occurs when you try to add a serie with name that is already existed in series collection! **Chart's series name should be unique**.

Probably strarr's values are not unique It contains multiple instance of same values.

So how to prevent it?Follow code bellow :-)

```
chart1.Series.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < intarr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (chart1.Series.FindByName(strarr[i])== null)
            {
                Series series = this.chart1.Series.Add(strarr[i]);
                series.Points.Add(intarr[i]);
                series.XValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
            }
        }
```

I suggest you to change  scenario as well,If you want further aids comment me.